# Very slow page load in jHipster application

Tags: load, jhipster

After having generated a few views and controllers for new entities in jHipster, I noticed that the application is loading in the browser very slowly. It takes almost 9 seconds to load all css and script files. I run the environment in development mode. The scripts are not minimized or concatenated. They load from a local server running in Vagrant.

Is this an issue specific to development?
Why do the scripts seem to load in sequence and not simultaneously?

Comment: Never experienced this with JHipster. Look at the stats in browser , how many files / KiloBytes. Are you running only java server (mvn or gradle) or the recommended dev setup using both gulp and java servers? Which version of JHipster and NodeJS?

Answer (score 5):

maybe this is an old question, but I will share my experience.

I was facing similar problem only in first request for `dev` mode, my browser spends about 5 seconds to get all resources, plus my laptop had low processing power "macbook-air".

then I started the application using `prod` profile, everything was good and fast. which is ok for me to make sure that the application will not be slow for end users.

so if you deploy the application using `prod` profile and it responds fast then you have nothing to worry about else we need to dig for more details.